# Send stream to electron app from express browser application in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, electron, webrtc

I have two different independent applications. My first application is electron desktop app while other is express app. I want to send and show stream from express application to electron nodejs app. I have used simple-peer library on express and done it on same localhost address but i have not find any solution to send data from localhost browser express app to electron desktop based app in NodeJS.

WebRTC is working proper on browser but there is not solution to connect two different applications through it.

If there is any example or running application, let me know.

Express application in NodeJS is sharing stream from initiator to its dependents on localhost. WebRTC simple-peer package is used in it for this purpose.

Electron application use getusermedia for stream separately from express. No link is yet developed how to connect express and electron application and share streaming.

Comment: Do you mean you have an electron app with node as a backend or do you have two completely independent applications? If you want to send data from the electron frontend to the nodejs backend you could have a look at electron IPC (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main). This only works if node is used as a backend for electron.

Comment: I have electron application with Node backend. I want to get stream from another independent Node express application on electron desktop app